# OpenLayers: How to move smaller vectors to front?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, z-index

I've got a problem that's been bugging me for quite some time now. As you can see in the image below I've got som vectors that ends up beneath bigger ones, and despite all my efforts of trying to figure out how to use zIndex to solve this, I just can't seem to get it right.

What I want is, due to limitation in getting the data, to detect features within the area of the bigger ones, and then just change the zIndex or something in order to get the smaller ones "above" the bigger polygons, thus making them selectable.

Right now I'm pretty much at a dead end, and desperatly searching for any clue or solution to this. 
Any ideas?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the source of the layers? Are they all vectors?

Comment: Question. So sometimes you want the bigger polygons on top and sometimes you want the smaller polygons on top? Is that correct? If that is true have you tried to dynamically change the opacity?

Comment: All vectors, and no, smallest always on top! Marking this as closed though, solved it by roughly calculating the area of the vectors, and with that setting z-index, thus making them align properly. It might fail at bigger sets of data, but for this application it works perfectly!

Comment: I'm currently dealing with the same problem. Can you post some example code, you used to solve the problem?